load sharing help
I’m designing an electronic circuit powered by 5V, with two possible power sources:

A 12V battery (regulated down to 5V using a 7805).
USB cable (providing 5V directly).

My goal is that if the system is powered via USB and I then connect the battery, the power should automatically switch to the battery. Important: I want to avoid using relays for this switching.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this efficiently?

The system has a maximum current consumption of 100-150 mA, but I want to avoid significant voltage drops, such as those that could occur with diodes. The output voltage of the system is 5V, which is used to power a CAN transceiver, for example, and I would like it to operate at 5V, especially when running on battery...
I was considering paralleling the V_USB and 7805_out outputs, with only one diode in series with the V_USB to manage the switching. Another option would be to implement a load sharing system with a P-channel MOSFET, but I’m concerned that since the voltages are very similar, the system might not work correctly. Alternatively, should I use the P-channel MOSFET to isolate the 12V input to the 7805?


what do you thing, this?
or this??


MikeBaxter - Hi, You posted an "answer" but it was actually more details which should be in the question, so I moved it into the question as an update. || Please see the site rules in the [tour] & [help] as Stack Exchange has different rules & etiquette to forums. Only answers to the original question should be written in the input box at the bottom of the page labeled "Your Answer". Since you asked the question, the only time you should use that input box is if you are writing a new, novel, full & final solution to your own question, which allows the question to be considered closed. TY

Why 7805? It is very inefficient and creates lots of heat. Not ideal together with a battery.

Anyway you could do this with a P MOSFET in series with the USB voltage. The gate is pulled low with a resistor, except when the battery voltage is present.

@Lundin - Thanks for trying to help, but please remember that comments shouldn't be used to answer a question - that's not an allowed use of them. Please see here for why answering in a comment can be harmful to the site & here for more details of the allowed uses of comments. Please consider posting it as an answer. TY

@SamGibson "Use a P MOSFET" is not answer, it's a loose suggestion. An answer would have to consider the Vgs voltages, Rds(on) and so on and suggest a part which might fit the bill.

@Lundin - Re: ' "Use a P MOSFET" is not answer ' Yes, it is. It's not an allowed use of comments. It isn't a very full answer, but it causes exactly the harm to the site explained at the link I provided. It also isn't one of the allowed uses of comments (requesting clarification / giving constructive criticism to improve the post / minor info). || A suggestion, as you called it, within the 3 categories of posts on SE, is an answer. It should be posted as an answer to say this is an approach which can be used (i.e. a suggestion) but more design work is needed to specify a MOSFET.

@SamGibson or @ Lundin - can you show me a schematic please, beacuse i think the load sharing in this situation don't work...thanks

@MikeBaxter - It was Lundin who kindly tried to help with their suggestion (misplaced as it was) so for the moment, I'll leave it for them to reply. || This is one of the reasons why suggested answers shouldn't be posted in comments. Comments (deliberately) can't be edited by normal site members to improve them or add new information, they don't display images inline & any points raised about one comment are mixed with other comments, rather than being associated with just that issue (as they would be, if the comments were posted on an answer). || P.S. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

There are a number of answer on this site covering this requirement.

Are you just trying to avoid the 0.7 V drop of an ordinary silicon diode or would the 0.3-4 V drop of a Schottky diode also be unacceptable and rule out the simple solution of using 2 Schottky diodes? Do you have a reason to use a 7805 instead of a more efficient buck regulator? Using one with an adjustable output would let you set the output voltage slightly higher than the USB source, giving you the requested battery priority.

@SamGibson Long discussions about how to use the site is even less suitable for comments... That's what meta is for. Where the community consensus seems to be something entirely different than what you are saying here. Meta post.

Possibly useful SEEE questions. || https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/29248/3288 ||https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/170076/3288 || https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/728016/3288 ||

@Lundin - I was going to suggest using Meta, so thanks for that. One problem which is not included in the Meta post you linked, is that mods get flags from site members here who, understandably, take a different view than yours (or from some in that Meta post you linked). So there is not a community consensus that you claim - far from it. We have long-standing site members that are unhappy with such answers in comments, and their flags require mods to get involved. I'll review the Meta post you linked, thanks for that, but currently my position remains the same, for the reasons I linked.

@SamGibson Everyone is welcome to express their opinion on meta. Those who didn't yet have a different opinion will be ignored - it's their loss. Answers in comments aren't allowed per official policy, but what consists as a valid answer is the subjective part where community consensus is needed. Especially if this particular site has a different take on it than most other sites on the network. This "Discussion of community behavior or site policies" is however not something up for discussion, it is discouraged on all sites in the network.

You can place two diodes in parallel, each connected to a power supply (12V and USB). These diodes will automatically route the higher voltage to the circuit.

Shamurov - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However this answer recommends that the OP uses diodes. Did you see the update to the question where they said: "I want to avoid significant voltage drops, such as those that could occur with diodes. ". At the moment, this answer does not seem to meet that constraint, does it? TY

Oh sorry, I did not see it. I can delete it.

Agreed with Sam. What you're describing, Shamurov, is "diode ORing". This has considerable amount of forward voltage drop.
